# Spring Data JPA Query Method returns double data when it's not present in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a web application that stores information about students, teachers, courses and grades. I have run into a problem while adding/editing students grades. For some reason the built in `findById()` method by the JPA Repository is returning a course with double the students (even though there is clearly only one student in that class in the database). I have attached images of my models and method also my attempt at debugging the problem.

Here is where the method is being called, my `listStudentsByCourse` method just returns a list of students:

[image]

Here is the `listStudentsByCourse` methods body:

[image]

Here are my models:

**Student:**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Grade> grades;


    public Student(String username, String password, String name, String surname) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.grades = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Character getGradeForCourse (Course c) {
        return this.grades.stream()
                .filter(i -> i.getCourse().getCourseId().equals(c.getCourseId()))
                .findFirst().orElse(new Grade()).getGrade();
    }

}
```

**Course:**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long courseId;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Teacher teacher;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Student> students;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;

    public Course(String name, String description, Teacher teacher, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.type = type;
        this.students = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

**Grade:**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Grade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Character grade;

    @ManyToOne
    private Course course;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    public Grade(Character grade, Course course, Student student, LocalDateTime timestamp) {
        this.grade = grade;
        this.course = course;
        this.student = student;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

**My database schema:**
[image]

**Image of the problem:**
[image]

This is the `course` that is returned by `courseRepository.findById()`

I have the same student added in one other course and I wonder if they are getting mixed up somehow, but that shouldn't be possible because the course is different (and so is the ID).
[image]

This problem is really giving me a hard time and I really don't understand how this is happening. Any info would be helpful, thanks!

**Edit 1:**
I read all of the comments and added them to my code, but the problem persists. I have now noticed that the data doubles when I have one student with a grade already in the course, and if I add another new student without a grade the data doubles not only on the front-end but also in the database.

Here is how I add new students to an existing course, is there anything wrong in the code?:

```
@Override
    public Course addStudentInCourse(String username, Long courseId) {

        if (this.studentRepository.findByUsername(username).isEmpty()) {
            throw new StudentNotFoundException();
        }

        if (this.courseRepository.findById(courseId).isEmpty()) {
            throw new CourseNotFoundException();
        }

        Student s = this.studentRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        Course c = this.courseRepository.findById(courseId).get();

        if (!c.getStudents().contains(s)){
            c.getStudents().add(s);
            return this.courseRepository.save(c);
        } else {
            return c;
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2:**
I have come to a breakthrough, sort of.

First of all, here is a picture of my `course_student` table:

[image]

I realized that `courseService.findById(courseId)`, if I have the same student in different courses, it retrieves that student as well (when it shouldn't). For example I have `markos` in course 5 and course 7.

If I use the following query method to return a list of the students in a certain course, it retrieves the students correctly.
`studentRepository.findAllByCourses(c);`

Here is a picture from my debugging:

[image]

I should probably note that the courses for a `Student` are Lazy Loaded.

[image]

**Why is the query method `findById` returning a `Course` with students that are not related to that course?**

**Edit 3:** All of the tables and code is the same from edit number 2 (I just kept refreshing the page where I fetch the data). I logged the SQL as many of you suggested. The following SQL queries are from the `courseService.findById(courseId)` method. I understand the first part, it fetches the course with the correct id (7) from the `Course` table. Then it selects a student from the `course_student` table where the id is 5. Where did this 5 come from?

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        course0_.course_id as course_i1_0_0_,
        course0_.description as descript2_0_0_,
        course0_.name as name3_0_0_,
        course0_.teacher_id as teacher_5_0_0_,
        course0_.type as type4_0_0_,
        students1_.fk_course as fk_cours1_1_1_,
        student2_.username as fk_stude2_1_1_,
        student2_.username as username1_3_2_,
        student2_.name as name2_3_2_,
        student2_.password as password3_3_2_,
        student2_.surname as surname4_3_2_,
        grades3_.fk_student as fk_stude5_2_3_,
        grades3_.id as id1_2_3_,
        grades3_.id as id1_2_4_,
        grades3_.fk_course as fk_cours4_2_4_,
        grades3_.grade as grade2_2_4_,
        grades3_.fk_student as fk_stude5_2_4_,
        grades3_.timestamp as timestam3_2_4_,
        course4_.course_id as course_i1_0_5_,
        course4_.description as descript2_0_5_,
        course4_.name as name3_0_5_,
        course4_.teacher_id as teacher_5_0_5_,
        course4_.type as type4_0_5_,
        teacher5_.id as id1_4_6_,
        teacher5_.date_of_employment as date_of_2_4_6_,
        teacher5_.name as name3_4_6_,
        teacher5_.surname as surname4_4_6_ 
    from
        course course0_ 
    left outer join
        course_student students1_ 
            on course0_.course_id=students1_.fk_course 
    left outer join
        student student2_ 
            on students1_.fk_student=student2_.username 
    left outer join
        grade grades3_ 
            on student2_.username=grades3_.fk_student 
    left outer join
        course course4_ 
            on grades3_.fk_course=course4_.course_id 
    left outer join
        teacher teacher5_ 
            on course4_.teacher_id=teacher5_.id 
    where
        course0_.course_id=?
2022-01-06 00:56:38.869 TRACE 15804 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [7]
Hibernate: 
    select
        students0_.fk_course as fk_cours1_1_0_,
        students0_.fk_student as fk_stude2_1_0_,
        student1_.username as username1_3_1_,
        student1_.name as name2_3_1_,
        student1_.password as password3_3_1_,
        student1_.surname as surname4_3_1_ 
    from
        course_student students0_ 
    inner join
        student student1_ 
            on students0_.fk_student=student1_.username 
    where
        students0_.fk_course=?
2022-01-06 00:56:38.881 TRACE 15804 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
Hibernate: 
    select
        course0_.course_id as course_i1_0_0_,
        course0_.description as descript2_0_0_,
        course0_.name as name3_0_0_,
        course0_.teacher_id as teacher_5_0_0_,
        course0_.type as type4_0_0_,
        students1_.fk_course as fk_cours1_1_1_,
        student2_.username as fk_stude2_1_1_,
        student2_.username as username1_3_2_,
        student2_.name as name2_3_2_,
        student2_.password as password3_3_2_,
        student2_.surname as surname4_3_2_,
        grades3_.fk_student as fk_stude5_2_3_,
        grades3_.id as id1_2_3_,
        grades3_.id as id1_2_4_,
        grades3_.fk_course as fk_cours4_2_4_,
        grades3_.grade as grade2_2_4_,
        grades3_.fk_student as fk_stude5_2_4_,
        grades3_.timestamp as timestam3_2_4_,
        course4_.course_id as course_i1_0_5_,
        course4_.description as descript2_0_5_,
        course4_.name as name3_0_5_,
        course4_.teacher_id as teacher_5_0_5_,
        course4_.type as type4_0_5_,
        teacher5_.id as id1_4_6_,
        teacher5_.date_of_employment as date_of_2_4_6_,
        teacher5_.name as name3_4_6_,
        teacher5_.surname as surname4_4_6_ 
    from
        course course0_ 
    left outer join
        course_student students1_ 
            on course0_.course_id=students1_.fk_course 
    left outer join
        student student2_ 
            on students1_.fk_student=student2_.username 
    left outer join
        grade grades3_ 
            on student2_.username=grades3_.fk_student 
    left outer join
        course course4_ 
            on grades3_.fk_course=course4_.course_id 
    left outer join
        teacher teacher5_ 
            on course4_.teacher_id=teacher5_.id 
    where
        course0_.course_id=?
2022-01-06 00:56:38.893 TRACE 15804 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [7]
Hibernate: 
    select
        students0_.fk_course as fk_cours1_1_0_,
        students0_.fk_student as fk_stude2_1_0_,
        student1_.username as username1_3_1_,
        student1_.name as name2_3_1_,
        student1_.password as password3_3_1_,
        student1_.surname as surname4_3_1_ 
    from
        course_student students0_ 
    inner join
        student student1_ 
            on students0_.fk_student=student1_.username 
    where
        students0_.fk_course=?
2022-01-06 00:56:38.909 TRACE 15804 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
```

Comment: Why are you using FetchType.EAGER?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I access the grades and students in others parts of the application and I needed them to be EAGER for that (otherwise I got the LazyLoading error).

Comment: I see the m2m mapping between course and student without a `joinTable` definition. Also, your join table in DB is with name `course_students` note `student*s*` I don't know how it works there without the `jointable` definition. Can you please try to add joinTable and test?

Comment: Also please turn on SQL logging an check the generated SQL statements

Comment: Have your tried `@JoinTable(...)` before defining `@ManyToMany` with `(mappedBy=...)`?

Comment: course_students is duplicating the data in the grade table, representing pretty  One student, one course, but the student could have taken that course a hundred times - check the number of entries in your two tables. Note that addStudentInCourse isn't synchronized, so nothing prevents it from adding the same relationship concurrently if hit twice before the first completes.  Is addStudentInCourse getting called in this chain of events? Could be that !c.getStudents().contains(s) isn't working the way you think it should - it depends on the student instance(s) and your hash/equals implementation

Comment: @Chris I mended the .contains(s) check and now I explicitly check by the username (which is my primary key), but I realized the problem is not with the addition of students, it's when I try to fetch a course that it takes students that don't belong there. Please check my second edit

Comment: Turn on logging and see the SQL that is generated - and when - for each step while debugging. The query that reads that join table might indicate what is going wrong and help point out why. My guess is that Hibernate is joining things and getting confused with the course->student->Grade->Course relationship. You might try making the grade->course lazy, or a different JPA provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions, I managed to figure it out.

It was the way I mapped my relationships all along. When I mapped the courses in my `Grade` entity as a ManyToOne, I had forgotten to map the grades in my `Course` entity with a OneToMany annotation. This resulted in Hibernate getting confused and fetching the same student for the course from two tables.

This is a lesson to always map your relationships correctly and don't lean on Hibernate to "figure it out".

Answer (score 1):

Your entity Course relationship with entity Student is Many-to-Many. That means rows of Course that have same id can hold many Students. I suspected that when you call `findById()` the generated SQL doesn't distinctively select the student given the courseId.

There's a catch in your schemas, which is the `course_students` that is not yet implemented in your code. This is a try suggestion, add `@JoinTable(...)` in your Course entity:

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long course_id;
.
.
   // your course fields
.
.
    /*** Here you add the many to many table ***/
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "course_students",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "course_course_id", referencedColumnName = "course_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "students_username", referencedColumnName = "username")})
    private List<Student> students;
 
... //more fields
}
```

And then in your Student entity, specify your mapped attribute from the join table:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private String username;

.. // student fields

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    List<Course> courses;

.. //more..
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, they didn't teach us this on our course so I did some more googling and found this useful. However I realized that findById fetches the course with students that not belong to it. I think somewhere during the query it selects the students from both tables? Not sure though, can you check out my second edit and tell me what you think?

Comment: Maybe not only `@ManyToMany`, you might want to try add `@JoinColumn(...)` as well for all the foreigned fields in each Grade, Student, and Course.